# PHP array_search help needed

Tags: php

I have an API function that returns JSON and I'm calling it like this to convert to an object:

```
$objParts = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com/api/GetPartTypes"));
```

Here is `print_r($objParts)` result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [parttype] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 103
                    [desc] => Spoiler Valance, Fr
                    [l1] => Body & Frame
                    [l2] => Exterior/Interior Trim
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 104
                    [desc] => Grille
                    [l1] => Body & Frame
                    [l2] => Hood
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 105
                    [desc] => Bumper Assy, Front
                    [l1] => Body & Frame
                    [l2] => Hood
                )
    )
)
```

I'd like to be able to return only the "object" where the `id` matches a parameter called `$parttype` without using a `foreach()` loop.
(`$objParts` contains over 400 items)
I know about `array_search()` but am unsure how to use it in the case above. This doesn't work:

```
$parttype = 104;
$val = array_search($parttype, $objParts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For PHP 5x (not 7), you'll have to use arrays with the functions, so this is a method to reach that result.*

Mix `array_column`, with `array_search`, and `json_decode` in associative array mode:

```
$objParts = json_decode($yourjson,true); // include 'true' here
$parttype = 104;
$val = array_search($parttype, array_column($objParts['parttype'], 'id'));
// $val will be '1' in this example

$found = $objParts['parttype'][$val];
```

To convert that back to an object of stdClass:

```
$found = (object)$objParts['parttype'][$val];
```

Result:

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [id] => 104
>       [desc] => Grille
>       [l1] => Body & Frame
>       [l2] => Hood
>   )

Comment: I can't decode to associative due to using it as an object later in the script.

Comment: Well, I am a little mistaken. It is used as an object in the `foreach()` and since I'm replacing that, it can now be associative.

Comment: If you are on PHP 7+, then assoc wont be needed. See Nigel's answer.

Comment: Ah, then yeah... this would work. You still end up with an object if you need it. It just needs a few extra bits. PHP 7 clearly has some better handling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PHP 7 and up you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) on objects, so just add...

```
$objParts = json_decode(file_get_contents("t.json"));
print_r($objParts);
$parttype = 104;
$item = array_search($parttype, array_column($objParts->parttype, "id"));

echo $objParts->parttype[$item]->desc;
```

Comment: "*PHP 7 and up*" ... good to know. I was on 5.6 when testing, thus couldn't get it to work ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I should set up another docker machine so I can test things pre 7.1, just in case some things don't work (not that they would break things in PHP >;)